# why is my code still displaying the old panes?

Tags: python, pygame, pane

So basically I have a two separate screens that I want displayed. One that has 11 Panes displayed on the screen at one time and once I click on a Pane named keyboard it should clear the screen and set up 36 Panes which should display a keyboard (for test purposes I only used three panes).

My problem is that once I click on keyboard it does clear the screen and display the 3 test panes how it also display's my other 10 panes that come from the first page.

**Example:**
This is fine to start with:
[image: Fine Display]

This is not fine. (A, B And C should be displayed but the rest shouldn't):
[image: Not Fine]

Here is the code:

```
import pygame
import sys
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
objs = []
MAIN_BUTTON = 2

KEYBOARD = True
WORDS = False


class Pane():

    def __init__(self, textToDisplay, coordinates, screen):
        self.textToDisplay = textToDisplay
        self.coordinates = coordinates
        self.screen = screen
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Palace Script MT', 25)
        Screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1366,768), 0, 32)
        self.screen = Screen
        self.screen.fill((white))

    def coordinates(self):
        return self.coordinates

    def text(self):
        return self.textToDisplay

    def drawPane(self):
        textCoords = self.coordinates        
        self.screen.blit(self.font.render(self.textToDisplay, True, (black)), textCoords)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (black), self.coordinates, 2)
        pygame.display.update()


class Screen():


    NoOfPanes = 0
    Panes = []
    paneLocs = [(583, 334, 300, 150), 
                (633, 150, 200, 125), 
                (633, 600, 200, 125), 
                (350, 360, 200, 100), 
                (925, 360, 200, 100), 
                (1000, 150, 150, 100), 
                (275, 150, 150, 100), 
                (275, 600, 150, 100), 
                (1000, 600, 150, 100), 
                (75, 350, 200, 100),
                (0, 668, 200, 100)
                ]    

    keyboardPaneLocs = [(0, 100, 100, 100),
                        (0, 200, 100, 100),
                        (0, 300, 100, 100),
                        (0, 400, 100, 100)
                        ]

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption('Box Test')

        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 25)
        Screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1366,768), 0, 32)
        self.screen = Screen
        self.screen.fill((white))

        pygame.display.update()

    def addPane(self, textToDisplay, keyboardFlag):      
        if (not keyboardFlag) and (self.NoOfPanes > 11):
            print("Limit Reached")            
        else:
            print(int(self.NoOfPanes))

            if keyboardFlag:
                newPane = Pane(textToDisplay, self.keyboardPaneLocs[self.NoOfPanes], Screen)
            else:
                newPane = Pane(textToDisplay, self.paneLocs[self.NoOfPanes], Screen)
            self.Panes.append(newPane)            

            self.NoOfPanes = self.NoOfPanes + 1
            pygame.display.update()


    def drawPanes(self):
        for Pane in self.Panes:
            Pane.drawPane()

    def mousePosition(self):
        global clickPos
        global releasePos
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == MAIN_BUTTON:
                self.Pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                return MAIN_BUTTON
            else:
                return False

    def mouseDown(self, posx, posy):
        textToReturn = "Nothing selected"
        for Pane in self.Panes:
            paneCoords = Pane.coordinates
            print(str(paneCoords[0]) + ":" + str(paneCoords[1]) + ":" + str(paneCoords[2]) + ":" + str(paneCoords[3]))
            if (paneCoords[0] <= posx <= paneCoords[0]+paneCoords[2]) and (paneCoords[1] <= posy <= paneCoords[1]+paneCoords[3]):            
                textToReturn = Pane.text()

        return textToReturn

    def displayKeyboard(self):
        self.addPane("A", KEYBOARD)
        self.addPane("B", KEYBOARD)
        self.addPane("C", KEYBOARD)

    def clearScreen(self):
        Screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1366,768), 0, 32)
        self.screen = Screen
        self.screen.fill((white))





if __name__ == '__main__':

    myScreen = Screen()
    myScreen.addPane("1", WORDS)
    myScreen.addPane("2", WORDS)
    myScreen.addPane("3", WORDS)
    myScreen.addPane("4", WORDS)
    myScreen.addPane("5", WORDS)
    myScreen.addPane("6", WORDS)
    myScreen.addPane("7", WORDS)
    myScreen.addPane("8", WORDS)
    myScreen.addPane("9", WORDS)
    myScreen.addPane("10", WORDS)
    myScreen.addPane("Keyboard", WORDS)

    myScreen.drawPanes()


    while True:
        ev = pygame.event.get()
        for event in ev:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                posx,posy = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                textSelected = myScreen.mouseDown(posx, posy)
                print(textSelected)
                if textSelected == "Keyboard":
                    myScreen = Screen()
                    myScreen.clearScreen()
                    myScreen.displayKeyboard()
                    myScreen.drawPanes()

        for event in pygame.event.get():        
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit(); sys.exit();
```

I think the problem that I am facing is that all of these panes are being added to the list `Panes = []`. How can I make sure that this list is clear before I display the new panes through the use of the function `def drawPanes(self):`

Don't take my word for it as it is just an assumption and I am well and truly stuck.
(Any help is appreciated.)

Comment: I don't have PyGame to test here, maybe if you try self.Panes = [] at the end of the clearScreen function. Be careful with members you declare at the class level, I had bad surprises especially in Python 2. You'd better have self.Panes = [] in your __init__ function.

Comment: Thank-you very much. Was very helpful. It all works now.

Comment: @PythonNovice I add full working example in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assing empty list to Pane to make it empty

```
Panes = []
```

but you will lost all added panes forever.

Maybe you should make seperated list for keyboard panes and than draw only this list.

**EDIT:**

By the way:

You use one variable `myScreen` to both screens - when you run `myScreen = Screen(...)` you create new screen but loose access to previous screen.

Using `Screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1366,768), 0, 32); self.screen = Screen` to clear screen is waste of time and memories. You need only `self.screen.fill((white))`

You use `Screen` name as class name and as variable in some functions. You can have accidentally name conflict.

**EDIT:**

Full working example how code could look like:

I use one `self.screen` so window isn't created/deleted everytime.

You can press "ESC" key to show/hide keyboard.

```
import pygame
import sys

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0  ,0  ,0  )

#---------------------------

MAIN_BUTTON = 2

KEYBOARD = True
WORDS = False

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Pane():

    def __init__(self, textToDisplay, coordinates, screen):

        self.textToDisplay = textToDisplay
        self.coordinates = coordinates
        self.screen = screen
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Palace Script MT', 25)

    #---------------------------

    def coordinates(self):
        return self.coordinates

    #---------------------------

    def text(self):
        return self.textToDisplay

    #---------------------------

    def drawPane(self):
        textCoords = self.coordinates        
        self.screen.blit(self.font.render(self.textToDisplay, True, BLACK), textCoords)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, BLACK, self.coordinates, 2)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Application():

    NoOfPanes = 0
    NoOfKeys = 0
    Panes = []
    Keys = []

    paneLocs = [(583, 334, 300, 150), 
                (633, 150, 200, 125), 
                (633, 600, 200, 125), 
                (350, 360, 200, 100), 
                (925, 360, 200, 100), 
                (1000, 150, 150, 100), 
                (275, 150, 150, 100), 
                (275, 600, 150, 100), 
                (1000, 600, 150, 100), 
                (75, 350, 200, 100),
                (0, 668, 200, 100)
                ]    

    keyboardPaneLocs = [(0, 100, 100, 100),
                        (0, 200, 100, 100),
                        (0, 300, 100, 100),
                        (0, 400, 100, 100)
                        ]

    #---------------------------

    def __init__(self):

        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption('Box Test')

        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 25)
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1366,768), 0, 32)

        self.show_panes = True
        self.show_keyboard = False

        self.createPanes()
        self.createKeyboard()

    #---------------------------

    def close(self):
        print "pygame quit"
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

    #---------------------------

    def createPanes(self):
        self.addPane("1", WORDS)
        self.addPane("2", WORDS)
        self.addPane("3", WORDS)
        self.addPane("4", WORDS)
        self.addPane("5", WORDS)
        self.addPane("6", WORDS)
        self.addPane("7", WORDS)
        self.addPane("8", WORDS)
        self.addPane("9", WORDS)
        self.addPane("10", WORDS)
        self.addPane("Keyboard", WORDS)

    #---------------------------

    def createKeyboard(self):
        self.addPane("A", KEYBOARD)
        self.addPane("B", KEYBOARD)
        self.addPane("C", KEYBOARD)

    #---------------------------

    def addPane(self, textToDisplay, keyboardFlag):      
        if (not keyboardFlag) and (self.NoOfPanes > 11):
            print("Limit Reached")            
        else:
            print(int(self.NoOfPanes))

            if keyboardFlag:
                self.Keys.append(Pane(textToDisplay, self.keyboardPaneLocs[self.NoOfKeys], self.screen))
                self.NoOfKeys += 1
            else:
                self.Panes.append(Pane(textToDisplay, self.paneLocs[self.NoOfPanes], self.screen))
                self.NoOfPanes += 1

    #---------------------------

    def drawPanes(self):
        for Pane in self.Panes:
            Pane.drawPane()

    #---------------------------

    def drawKeyboard(self):
        for Key in self.Keys:
            Key.drawPane()

    #---------------------------

    def mousePosition(self, event):
            if event.type == MAIN_BUTTON:
                self.Pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                return MAIN_BUTTON
            else:
                return False

    #---------------------------

    def mouseDown(self):
        posx,posy = pygame.mouse.get_pos()      
        textToReturn = "Nothing selected"
        if self.show_panes:
            for Pane in self.Panes:
                paneCoords = Pane.coordinates
                print(str(paneCoords[0]) + ":" + str(paneCoords[1]) + ":" + str(paneCoords[2]) + ":" + str(paneCoords[3]))
                if (paneCoords[0] <= posx <= paneCoords[0]+paneCoords[2]) and (paneCoords[1] <= posy <= paneCoords[1]+paneCoords[3]):            
                    textToReturn = Pane.text()
        elif self.show_keyboard:
            for Pane in self.Keys:
                paneCoords = Pane.coordinates
                print(str(paneCoords[0]) + ":" + str(paneCoords[1]) + ":" + str(paneCoords[2]) + ":" + str(paneCoords[3]))
                if (paneCoords[0] <= posx <= paneCoords[0]+paneCoords[2]) and (paneCoords[1] <= posy <= paneCoords[1]+paneCoords[3]):            
                    textToReturn = Pane.text()

        return textToReturn

    #---------------------------

    def run(self):

        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        RUNNING = True
        while RUNNING:

            # --- events ---

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    RUNNING = False
                    break

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        self.show_keyboard = not self.show_keyboard
                        self.show_panes = not self.show_panes

                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    textSelected = self.mouseDown()
                    print(textSelected)
                    if textSelected == "Keyboard":
                        self.show_keyboard = True
                        self.show_panes = False

            # --- draws ---

            self.screen.fill(WHITE)

            if self.show_panes:
                self.drawPanes()

            if self.show_keyboard:
                self.drawKeyboard()

            pygame.display.update()

            # --- FPS ---

            clock.tick(25)

        self.close()    
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

Application().run()
```

**EDIT:**

- Class Keyboard
- Pane has one event_handler
- Pane test if mouse is over
- Pane change background when mouse is over (yellow)
- Pane change background when mouse is pressed (red)
- clicking key Q on screen to close keyboard
- keyboard send own event to mainloop when key Q is click - to inform that keyboard is closed

.

```
import pygame
import sys

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0  ,0  ,0  )

#---------------------------

MAIN_BUTTON = 2

KEYBOARD = True
WORDS = False

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Pane():

    def __init__(self, textToDisplay, rect, screen, fgColor=(0,0,0), bgColor=(255,255,255), mouseoverBgColor=(255,255,0) ):

        self.textToDisplay = textToDisplay
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(*rect)
        self.screen = screen

        # colors

        self.fgColor = fgColor
        self.bgColor = bgColor

        self.mouseoverBgColor = mouseoverBgColor

        self.currentFgColor = self.fgColor
        self.currentBgColor = self.bgColor

        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Palace Script MT', 25)

    #---------------------------

    def coordinates(self):
        return self.rect

    #---------------------------

    def text(self):
        return self.textToDisplay

    #---------------------------

    def draw(self):
        # background
        self.screen.fill(self.currentBgColor, self.rect)

        # border
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.currentFgColor, self.rect, 2)

        # text
        self.screen.blit(self.font.render(self.textToDisplay, True, self.currentFgColor), self.rect)

    #---------------------------

    def test_coordinates(self, posx, posy):
        return self.rect.collidepoint(posx, posy)

    #---------------------------

    def event_handler(self, event):

        # standard pane color
        self.currentFgColor = self.fgColor
        self.currentBgColor = self.bgColor

        # if mouse over pane change color

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                self.currentBgColor = self.mouseoverBgColor

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                self.currentBgColor = (255,0,0)

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                self.currentBgColor = self.mouseoverBgColor

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Keyboard():

    Keys = []
    paneLocs = []
    visible = False
    #---------------------------

    def __init__(self, screen):

        self.screen = screen
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 25)

        self.create()

    #---------------------------

    def create(self):

        letter_code = ord("A")

        for y in range(2):
            for x in range(13):
                lock = (100*x, 100*y, 100, 100)
                self.paneLocs.append(lock)
                self.Keys.append(Pane(chr(letter_code), lock, self.screen, (0,0,0), (0,255,0)))
                letter_code += 1

    #---------------------------

    def draw(self):
        for key in self.Keys:
            key.draw()

    #---------------------------

    def event_handler(self, event):

        textToReturn = None

        # let panes handle event
        for key in self.Keys:
            key.event_handler(event)

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            posx, posy = event.pos
            for key in self.Keys:
                #print "debug: keyboard.event_handler", posx, posy
                if key.test_coordinates(posx, posy):
                    textToReturn = key.text()       

                    print textToReturn

            # if Q was 
            if textToReturn == 'Q':
                self.onKeyQ(textToReturn)

        return textToReturn

    #---------------------------

    def onKeyQ(self, text):

        # hide keyboard
        self.visible = False

        # send event to inform main loop that keyboard was closed
        pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(pygame.USEREVENT, {'code': 666, 'key':text}))

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Application():

    NoOfPanes = 0
    Panes = []

    paneLocs = [(583, 334, 300, 150), 
                (633, 150, 200, 125), 
                (633, 600, 200, 125), 
                (350, 360, 200, 100), 
                (925, 360, 200, 100), 
                (1000, 150, 150, 100), 
                (275, 150, 150, 100), 
                (275, 600, 150, 100), 
                (1000, 600, 150, 100), 
                (75, 350, 200, 100),
                (0, 668, 200, 100)
                ]    

    #---------------------------

    def __init__(self):

        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption('Box Test')

        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 25)
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1366,768), 0, 32)

        self.show_panes = True

        self.createPanes()

        self.keyboard = Keyboard(self.screen)

    #---------------------------

    def close(self):
        print "pygame quit"
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

    #---------------------------

    def createPanes(self):
        self.addPane("1", WORDS)
        self.addPane("2", WORDS)
        self.addPane("3", WORDS)
        self.addPane("4", WORDS)
        self.addPane("5", WORDS)
        self.addPane("6", WORDS)
        self.addPane("7", WORDS)
        self.addPane("8", WORDS)
        self.addPane("9", WORDS)
        self.addPane("10", WORDS)
        self.addPane("Keyboard", WORDS)

    #---------------------------

    def addPane(self, textToDisplay, keyboardFlag):      
        if (not keyboardFlag) and (self.NoOfPanes > 11):
            print("Limit Reached")            
        else:
            print(int(self.NoOfPanes))

            if not keyboardFlag:
                self.Panes.append(Pane(textToDisplay, self.paneLocs[self.NoOfPanes], self.screen))
                self.NoOfPanes += 1

    #---------------------------

    def drawPanes(self):
        for Pane in self.Panes:
            Pane.draw()

    #---------------------------

    def mousePosition(self, event):
            if event.type == MAIN_BUTTON:
                self.Pos = event.pos
                return MAIN_BUTTON
            else:
                return False

    #---------------------------

    def event_handler(self, event):

        textToReturn = None

        # let panes handle events
        for pane in self.Panes:
            pane.event_handler(event)

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            posx, posy = event.pos
            for pane in self.Panes:
                #print "debug: app.event_handler", posx, posy
                if pane.test_coordinates(posx, posy):
                    textToReturn = pane.text()

                    if textToReturn == "Keyboard":
                        self.keyboard.visible = True
                        self.show_panes = False

                    print textToReturn
        return textToReturn

    #---------------------------

    def run(self):

        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        RUNNING = True
        while RUNNING:

            # --- events ---

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    RUNNING = False
                    break

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        self.keyboard.visible = not self.keyboard.visible
                        self.show_panes = not self.show_panes


                if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
                    print "USEREVENT:", event.code
                    # event from keyboard
                    if event.code == 666:
                        # keyboar was closed so I have to show panes
                        self.show_panes = True

                if self.show_panes:
                    self.event_handler(event)

                if self.keyboard.visible:
                    self.keyboard.event_handler(event)

            # --- draws ---

            self.screen.fill(WHITE)

            if self.show_panes:
                self.drawPanes()

            if self.keyboard.visible:
                self.keyboard.draw()

            pygame.display.update()

            # --- FPS ---

            clock.tick(25)

        self.close()    

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

Application().run()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Now Pane can be clicked and moved. I put here only Pane class

Look for: `is_movable` and `is_moving`

```
class Pane():

    def __init__(self, textToDisplay, rect, screen, fgColor=(0,0,0), bgColor=(255,255,255), mouseoverBgColor=(255,255,0) ):

        self.textToDisplay = textToDisplay
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(*rect)
        self.screen = screen

        # colors

        self.fgColor = fgColor
        self.bgColor = bgColor

        self.mouseoverBgColor = mouseoverBgColor

        self.currentFgColor = self.fgColor
        self.currentBgColor = self.bgColor

        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Palace Script MT', 25)

        self.is_movable = True
        self.is_moving = False
    #---------------------------

    def coordinates(self):
        return self.rect

    #---------------------------

    def text(self):
        return self.textToDisplay

    #---------------------------

    def draw(self):
        # background
        self.screen.fill(self.currentBgColor, self.rect)

        # border
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.currentFgColor, self.rect, 2)

        # text
        self.screen.blit(self.font.render(self.textToDisplay, True, self.currentFgColor), self.rect)

    #---------------------------

    def test_coordinates(self, posx, posy):
        return self.rect.collidepoint(posx, posy)

    #---------------------------

    def event_handler(self, event):

        # standard pane color
        self.currentFgColor = self.fgColor
        self.currentBgColor = self.bgColor

        # if mouse over pane change color

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                self.currentBgColor = self.mouseoverBgColor

                if self.is_movable and self.is_moving:
                    self.rect.move_ip(event.rel)
                    self.currentBgColor = (0,0,255)

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                self.currentBgColor = (255,0,0)
                self.is_moving = True

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                self.currentBgColor = self.mouseoverBgColor
                self.is_moving = False
```

**EDIT:**

Clicked Pane become top-most Pane on screen:

```
import pygame
import sys

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0  ,0  ,0  )

#---------------------------

MAIN_BUTTON = 2

KEYBOARD = True
WORDS = False

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class evt_type(): # UserEvent - types

    PANE     = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
    KEYBOARD = pygame.USEREVENT + 2

class evt_code(): # UserEvent - codes

   KEYBOARD_CLOSED = 100
   PANE_CLICKED = 200

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Pane():

    def __init__(self, textToDisplay, rect, screen, fgColor=(0,0,0), bgColor=(255,255,255), mouseoverBgColor=(255,255,0) ):

        self.textToDisplay = textToDisplay
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(*rect)
        self.screen = screen

        # colors

        self.fgColor = fgColor
        self.bgColor = bgColor

        self.mouseoverBgColor = mouseoverBgColor

        self.currentFgColor = self.fgColor
        self.currentBgColor = self.bgColor

        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Palace Script MT', 25)

        self.is_movable = True
        self.is_moving = False
    #---------------------------

    def coordinates(self):
        return self.rect

    #---------------------------

    def text(self):
        return self.textToDisplay

    #---------------------------

    def draw(self):
        # background
        self.screen.fill(self.currentBgColor, self.rect)

        # border
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.currentFgColor, self.rect, 2)

        # text
        self.screen.blit(self.font.render(self.textToDisplay, True, self.currentFgColor), self.rect)

    #---------------------------

    def test_coordinates(self, posx, posy):
        return self.rect.collidepoint(posx, posy)

    #---------------------------

    def event_handler(self, event):

        # standard pane color
        self.currentFgColor = self.fgColor
        self.currentBgColor = self.bgColor

        # if mouse over pane change color

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                self.currentBgColor = self.mouseoverBgColor

                if self.is_movable and self.is_moving:
                    self.rect.move_ip(event.rel)
                    self.currentBgColor = (0,0,255)

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                if self.is_movable:
                    pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(evt_type.PANE, {'code': evt_code.PANE_CLICKED, 'widget': self}))
                self.currentBgColor = (255,0,0)
                self.is_moving = True

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                self.currentBgColor = self.mouseoverBgColor
            self.is_moving = False


#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Keyboard():

    Keys = []
    paneLocs = []
    visible = False
    #---------------------------

    def __init__(self, screen):

        self.screen = screen
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 25)

        self.create()

    #---------------------------

    def create(self):

        letter_code = ord("A")

        for y in range(2):
            for x in range(13):
                lock = (100*x, 100*y, 100, 100)
                self.paneLocs.append(lock)
                self.Keys.append(Pane(chr(letter_code), lock, self.screen, (0,0,0), (0,255,0)))
                self.Keys[-1].is_movable = False
                letter_code += 1

    #---------------------------

    def draw(self):
        for key in self.Keys:
            key.draw()

    #---------------------------

    def event_handler(self, event):

        textToReturn = None

        # let panes handle event
        for key in self.Keys:
            key.event_handler(event)

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            posx, posy = event.pos
            for key in self.Keys:
                #print "debug: keyboard.event_handler", posx, posy
                if key.test_coordinates(posx, posy):
                    textToReturn = key.text()       

                    print textToReturn

            # if Q was 
            if textToReturn == 'Q':
                self.onKeyQ(textToReturn)

        return textToReturn

    #---------------------------

    def onKeyQ(self, text):

        # hide keyboard
        self.visible = False

        # send event to inform main loop that keyboard was closed
        pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(evt_type.KEYBOARD, {'code': evt_code.KEYBOARD_CLOSED, 'key':text}))

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Application():

    NoOfPanes = 0
    Panes = []

    paneLocs = [(583, 334, 300, 150), 
                (633, 150, 200, 125), 
                (633, 600, 200, 125), 
                (350, 360, 200, 100), 
                (925, 360, 200, 100), 
                (1000, 150, 150, 100), 
                (275, 150, 150, 100), 
                (275, 600, 150, 100), 
                (1000, 600, 150, 100), 
                (75, 350, 200, 100),
                (0, 668, 200, 100)
                ]    

    #---------------------------

    def __init__(self):

        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption('Box Test')

        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 25)
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1366,768), 0, 32)

        self.show_panes = True

        self.createPanes()

        self.keyboard = Keyboard(self.screen)

    #---------------------------

    def close(self):
        print "pygame quit"
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

    #---------------------------

    def createPanes(self):
        self.addPane("1", WORDS)
        self.addPane("2", WORDS)
        self.addPane("3", WORDS)
        self.addPane("4", WORDS)
        self.addPane("5", WORDS)
        self.addPane("6", WORDS)
        self.addPane("7", WORDS)
        self.addPane("8", WORDS)
        self.addPane("9", WORDS)
        self.addPane("10", WORDS)
        self.addPane("Keyboard", WORDS)

    #---------------------------

    def addPane(self, textToDisplay, keyboardFlag):      
        if (not keyboardFlag) and (self.NoOfPanes > 11):
            print("Limit Reached")            
        else:
            print(int(self.NoOfPanes))

            if not keyboardFlag:
                self.Panes.append(Pane(textToDisplay, self.paneLocs[self.NoOfPanes], self.screen))
                self.NoOfPanes += 1

    #---------------------------

    def drawPanes(self):
        for Pane in self.Panes:
            Pane.draw()

    #---------------------------

    def mousePosition(self, event):
            if event.type == MAIN_BUTTON:
                self.Pos = event.pos
                return MAIN_BUTTON
            else:
                return False

    #---------------------------

    def event_handler(self, event):

        textToReturn = None

        # let panes handle events
        for pane in self.Panes:
            pane.event_handler(event)

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            posx, posy = event.pos
            for pane in self.Panes:
                #print "debug: app.event_handler", posx, posy
                if pane.test_coordinates(posx, posy):
                    textToReturn = pane.text()

                    if textToReturn == "Keyboard":
                        self.keyboard.visible = True
                        self.show_panes = False

                    print textToReturn
        return textToReturn

    #---------------------------

    def run(self):

        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        RUNNING = True
        while RUNNING:

            # --- events ---

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    RUNNING = False
                    break

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        self.keyboard.visible = not self.keyboard.visible
                        self.show_panes = not self.show_panes


                if event.type == evt_type.KEYBOARD:
                    print "USEREVENT:: TYPE:", event.type, "CODE:", event.code
                    # event from keyboard
                    if event.code == evt_code.KEYBOARD_CLOSED:
                        # keyboar was closed so I have to show panes
                        self.show_panes = True

                if event.type == evt_type.PANE:
                    print "USEREVENT:: TYPE:", event.type, "CODE:", event.code
                    if event.code == evt_code.PANE_CLICKED:
                        # move to the end - move to top of screen
                        index = self.Panes.index(event.widget)
                        self.Panes.append(self.Panes.pop(index))

                if self.show_panes:
                    self.event_handler(event)

                if self.keyboard.visible:
                    self.keyboard.event_handler(event)

            # --- draws ---

            self.screen.fill(WHITE)

            if self.show_panes:
                self.drawPanes()

            if self.keyboard.visible:
                self.keyboard.draw()

            pygame.display.update()

            # --- FPS ---

            clock.tick(25)

        self.close()    

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

Application().run()
```

Comment: Thank-you very much for your help. I don't know why but sometimes I just struggle with the simplest of things. It's frustrating.

Comment: I got to say friend thank-you once again. The way that you have done it is a lot tidier  than my method also it's a lot more efficient so thank-you very much. :)

Comment: I had one more idea - to make `class Keyboard` with own `create()`, `draw()`, `event_handler(event)`, and `Panes` list for keys.

Comment: Oh that sounds interesting. Would you care to explain further please?

Comment: Meanwhile I made Keyboard class and some modification - see code in my answer.

Comment: @PythonNovice now Pane can be moved by mouse - see in answer.It is no ideal - sometimes you can lose control on Pane.

Comment: Yet again thank-you very much. You have been of great help to me. I really couldn't thank-you enough. You have taught me a lot. Thank-You :D

Comment: I had fun with inventing new features. Meanwhile I made some modifications - now I don't lose control on moving pane, when I click pane it become top-most pane on screen so it doesn't move behind others. If I had time the next feature would be maximize pane to full screen and minimize to icon.

Comment: Sweet ideas mate. Well what can I say? I wish I could be as good as you at coding